# when running 'faiss.normalize_L2(embeddings)', showed 'zsh: segmentation fault'

Tags: embedding, faiss, similarity-search

Sorry I would like to use normalization for embeddings like this:

```
    index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(embeddings.shape[1])
    print(index.is_trained)
    faiss.normalize_L2(embeddings)
    index.add(embeddings)
```

But showed  'zsh: segmentation fault'...
Where is the bug from and how can I address it. Thanks a lot.